# Planetary physics are wonky

Tags: javascript, physics, p5.js

So in my physics class we're doing stuff with Kepler's law and other such equations. I figured I'd understand it better if i could make a model of it. and I've got it running... sorta. The motion of the planets, or moons in this instance, are supposed to be ellipses and they just aren't anywhere close.

I'm using actual masses, distances, and speeds for the planetoids so I'm not sure whats going wrong

```js
let G = 6.67408*Math.pow(10,-11)
let scl = 4000
let mars;
let phobos;
let deimos;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(600, 600)
 mars = new Planet(0, 0, 0, 0, 6.4171*pow(10,24))
 phobos = new Planet(-9234420, 0, 0, -2138 , 1.0659*pow(10,16))
 deimos = new Planet(23463200, 0, 0, 1351.3, 1.4762*pow(10,15))
 background(0)
}

function draw() {
 translate(width/2-mars.pos.x/scl, height/2-mars.pos.y/scl)
 background(0, 1)
 for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
  mars.show()
  phobos.show()
  deimos.show()
  mars.update()
  phobos.update()
  deimos.update()
  grav(phobos, mars)
  grav(mars, deimos)
  grav(phobos, deimos)
  
  if(deimos.pos.dist(mars.pos)/scl>(width/2)){
   scl = deimos.pos.dist(phobos.pos)/(0.99*width/2);
   background(0)
  }
  
 }
}

function force(p1, p2){
 d = p1.pos.dist(p2.pos)
 f = G*(p1.mass*p2.mass)/(d*d)
 return f
}

function grav(p1,p2){
 d1 = p2.pos.copy().sub(p1.pos).normalize()
 d2 = p1.pos.copy().sub(p2.pos).normalize()

 f = force(p1,p2)
 
 p1.acc.add(d1.mult(force/p1.mass))
 p2.acc.add(d2.mult(force/p2.mass))
}

function Planet(x, y, vx, vy, mass){
 this.mass = mass;
 this.pos = createVector(x, y)
 this.vel = createVector(vx, vy)
 this.acc = createVector(0, 0)
 
 this.show = function(){
  stroke(255)
  strokeWeight(width/100)
  point(this.pos.x/scl, this.pos.y/scl)
 }
 
 this.update = function(){
  this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel);
  this.vel = this.vel.add(this.acc)
  this.acc = this.acc.mult(0)
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

as i said one would think that they would have elliptical orbits yet they're not. so I'm just at a loss.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: its not that there is any one line of code that is misbehaving, its the motion of the planets themselves. One would assume that if using the actual measurements, then the motion would appear like the actual planets. all of my units are in base SI, so like meters kilograms, newtons. Im not using kilos or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

To make the physics work in this code we need to make a couple of corrections.

The `grav` function needs to calculate force and use it to update acceleration, however, there is a mistake that causes the force function to be used instead of the calculated force and the original code multiplies by NaN instead of force/mass as the `force` function is not a number.

```
function grav(p1,p2){
  d1 = p2.pos.copy().sub(p1.pos).normalize()
  d2 = p1.pos.copy().sub(p2.pos).normalize()

  f = force(p1,p2) // we need to store the calculated force
  p1.acc.add(d1.mult(f/(p1.mass))) // and use it here
  p2.acc.add(d2.mult(f/(p2.mass))) // and here
}
```

The code also needs to call `update` after each call to the `grav` function:

```
grav(phobos, mars);
mars.update();
phobos.update();

grav(mars, deimos);
mars.update();
deimos.update();

grav(phobos, deimos);
phobos.update();
deimos.update();
```

```js
let G = 6.67408*Math.pow(10,-11)
let scl = 4000
let mars;
let phobos;
let deimos;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  mars = new Planet(0, 0, 0, 0, 6.4171*pow(10,24));
  phobos = new Planet(-9234420, 0, 0, -2138 , 1.0659*pow(10,16));
  deimos = new Planet(23463200, 0, 0, 1351.3, 1.4762*pow(10,15));
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  translate(width/2-mars.pos.x/scl, height/2-mars.pos.y/scl);
  background(0, 1);
  for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    mars.show();
    phobos.show();
    deimos.show();

    grav(phobos, mars);
    mars.update();
    phobos.update();

    grav(mars, deimos);
    mars.update();
    deimos.update();
    
    grav(phobos, deimos);
    phobos.update();
    deimos.update();
    
    if(deimos.pos.dist(mars.pos)/scl>(width/2)){
      scl = deimos.pos.dist(phobos.pos)/(0.99*width/2);
      background(0)
   }
  }
}

function force(p1, p2){
 d = p1.pos.dist(p2.pos)
 f = G*(p1.mass*p2.mass)/(d*d)
 return f
}

function grav(p1,p2){
  let d1 = p2.pos.copy().sub(p1.pos).normalize()
  let d2 = p1.pos.copy().sub(p2.pos).normalize()

  let f = force(p1,p2)
  p1.acc.add(d1.mult(f/(p1.mass)))
  p2.acc.add(d2.mult(f/(p2.mass)))
}

function Planet(x, y, vx, vy, mass){
  this.mass = mass;
  this.pos = createVector(x, y)
  this.vel = createVector(vx, vy)
  this.acc = createVector(0, 0)

  this.show = function(){
    stroke(255)
    strokeWeight(width/100)
    point(this.pos.x/scl, this.pos.y/scl)
  }

  this.update = function(){
    this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.vel = this.vel.add(this.acc)
    this.acc = this.acc.mult(0)
  }
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

With these corrections we get roughly elliptical orbits, however, after a few revolutions the moons drift away from Mars. This is not surprising as all of the initial conditions and the value of G are approximations.